# How do I call a JS function from typescript in a browser without webpack or similar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker

I have a webworker written in TypeScript that needs to call a single function defined in a js lib.

Inlining the js code into the typescript file and adding type annotations isn't really an option because the js lib is huge, and doesn't follow my strict typescript type checker rules. Also, it might be a license violation; haven't checked yet.

How can I do this seemingly simple task?

Comment: latest typescript you may not need webpack

Comment: Off chance the library has a type definition file available? Many popular libraries do.

Comment: It does not, but I could easily write one myself as there aren't that many exposed functions; one objects with ~5 methods.

Comment: If you aren't using Webpack how is the JS library included in your build?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a usecase for [Typescript's Excludes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). If that does not work somehow, here is a workaround:

---

Just define some type interface for the library:

```
 interface ILibrary {
  someProp: number;
 }
```

Then in every file were you use that library, named `library`, just do:

```
 var library = library as ILibrary;
```

And then include the library source into the final webpage.

Comment: I specifically asked for a solution that didn't require setting up webpack or similar.

Comment: @filip oops, somehow skipped the healdine ... So you just use tsc right?

Comment: Yes. Running it from inside pycharm, but I don't think that makes a difference.